# How do i display the super mario environment on google colab

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

```
 done = True
    
    
    for step in range(100000):
    
     
      if done:
    
       
        env.reset()
    
     
      state, reward, done, info = env.step(env.action_space.sample())
      env.render()
    env.close()
```

when run this code i get this error

```
    AttributeError        Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pyglet/__init__.py in __getattr__(self, name)
    328         try:
--> 329             return getattr(self._module, name)
    330         except AttributeError:

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'key'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

NoSuchDisplayException                    Traceback (most recent call last)
11 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pyglet/canvas/xlib.py in __init__(self, name, x_screen)
    121         self._display = xlib.XOpenDisplay(name)
    122         if not self._display:
--> 123             raise NoSuchDisplayException('Cannot connect to "%s"' % name)
    124 
    125         screen_count = xlib.XScreenCount(self._display)

NoSuchDisplayException: Cannot connect to "None"
```

how do i display the other screen that displays the game i have tried using matplotlib along with all the necc. imports but its very slow and take a long time to complete the above steps so i had to reduce it to 5000 but still it took a long time in this youtube video this person doesnt install and extra packages and the rendering screen appears how do i do that? if its not possible on colab then how do i do it on jupyter notebook.
this link

[Setup a Mario Environment
Preprocess Mario for Applied Reinforcement Learning
Build a Reinforcement Learning model to play Mario
Take a look at the final results](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2eeYqJ0uBKE&t=941s)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend something like this. Its not perfect (little time between clear and next frame), but its the best and simplest solution I've found:

```py
from IPython.display import clear_output, display
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np


 done, truncated = True, True
 for step in range(100000):    

    if done: # or truncated
       env.reset()

    state, reward, done, info = env.step(env.action_space.sample())

    # OR for those who made the switch to gymnasium
    # state, reward, done, truncated, info = env.step(env.action_space.sample())

    # Grab image from env as array
    img = env.render(mode='rgb_array')

    # Display image with IPython; clear last iPython display on create
    display(Image.fromarray(np.array(img), 'RGB'), clear=True)

env.close()
```

This is also easy to modify to use PIL functions to resize the image before displaying if you want. You can use other IPython displays to show text stats that clear each frame also in a similar fashion using the info object returned

Answer (score 0):

Common practice when using gym on collab and wanting to watch videos of episodes you save them as mp4s, as there is no attached video device (and has benefit of allowing you to watch back at any time during the session).

You do this by wrapping your environment with the Monitor wrapper.

If this is during training for example you could save every 100 episodes using the following code:

```
video_every = 100
env = gym.wrappers.Monitor(env, "./video", video_callable=lambda episode_id: (episode_id%video_every)==0, force=True)

done = True
for step in range(100000):
    if done:
        env.reset()
    state, reward, done, info = env.step(env.action_space.sample())
env.close()
```

This saves a video of every `video_every`'th episode to the folder "video" (which you can access from the bar on the left of colab)

Comment: For anyone that is reading this in 2023, I have a working implementation on my github page of this approach using Gymnasium (the current maintained fork of Open AI gym) https://github.com/hom-bahrani/Gymnasium-Colaboratory-Starter

Answer (score 0):

As other answers explained, we do not have a video device, so we cannot directly output video. But we can record a video and safe it as a file, then we can download it and inspect it. The answer from @shadowbourne uses the `Monitor` wrapper, but the `Monitor` class was deprecated in newer versions of gym and we should now use the `RecodVideo` wrapper (see [RecordVideo](https://gymnasium.farama.org/api/wrappers/misc_wrappers/#gymnasium.wrappers.RecordVideo)).

You can initialize it like this:

```
# create an environment
env = gym.make("CartPole-v1")

# define a trigger function, return True to start recording a new video:
episode_trigger=lambda episode_id: (episode_id%video_every==0)

# decorate env with a video recorder:
env = gym.wrappers.RecordVideo(env, "./video",
         episode_trigger=episode_trigger, video_length=100000)
```

The episode trigger can be adjusted as needed. Here it returns `True` for the first episode, so this should generate a video starting with the first episode.

Then before you start your training loop call:

```
env.start_video_recorder()
```

Recording will run until you call `env.close()`.

Comment: I believe you mean `env.close()`